# A windows php stand-alone compiler that works with the Zend GData library and PHP 5.2x?

Tags: php, windows, compiler-construction

I am hoping there exists a: " php stand-alone compiler that works with the Zend GData library and PHP 5.2x."  For using with the following [php GCAL sync software](http://code.google.com/p/todolistgcalsync/wiki/ToDoList) for a software called todolist.

Answer (score 1):

There are only a [small](http://www.roadsend.com/home/index.php?pageID=compiler) [handful](http://www.phpcompiler.org/) of [compilers](http://wiki.github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/), none of which are guaranteed to work properly for all code.  You can also [run PHP on Java](http://quercus.caucho.com/), which might be slightly more sane.

Comment: I had no idea that PHP on Java existed. Huh